# Looking for time delay relay or relay circuit that can be reset

Tags: relay, delay, time

1. Need relay control that results in a closed contact (dry) that is held for 1 minute
2. If during that one minute another signal is received (dry or not) the 1 minute countdown resets.    The actual scenerio is: A car breaks a photo-eye beam, the photo eye relay closes (dry or not) which in turn directly (dry) or indirectly (if pulling another relay) eventually results in a dry contact closing which makes a parking exit gate go up and stay up for 1 minute... if however another vehicle arrives 43 sec into that minute I need to restart the 1 minute clock

Comment: So what have you come up with so far. We'll help you but generally won't do all your work for you. See the Help Center rules. In particular read about "shopping questions". Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Have you tried [searching this site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=delay+relay)? 202 answers for "relay" and "delay". Note your question will be closed unless you edit it, show us what you have tried so far, and provide a schematic.

Comment: Relay and a flipflop, done

Comment: Buy a timer relay with built in this function, off-delay

Comment: laptop2d... what do u mean by flip-flop?

Comment: Marko Bursic,,, I have a time with on-time and off-time settings... can't figure out how to keep it powered during the 1 minute and cause it to reset at say 37 seconds and restart the minute

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to build a circuit that has *One* input and *One* output, such that the output [**RELAY**] is kept high for 1 min. if the input signal is *HIGH*

You can build such a circuit using a micro-controller but as you mentioned in the comments you don`t want to program, of course you can build this circuit without uC, you can for example use a [555 timer IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC)  or you can build your own custom circuit. I have came up with a very very simple circuit that can do this job, i cant tell that this is the perfect solution for your question but it should work.

See the next image

[image]

In order to start your circuit, you should press the normally closed switch.

[image]

Once the switch is released, the compactor output will be **LOW** until your signal arrive

assuming your signal is just a pulse, once this pulse arrives the n MOSFET will short circuit the capacitor and the op-amp Comparator output will be **HIGH** until the capacitor re-charges again to a certain value *The time taken to charge must be 60 seconds*

[image]

And then once the capacitor is charged the relay is turned off

*What if the signal came twice while the output is still high ?*

The circuit will do the same behavior that you wish, which is the time is reset and another 60 seconds starts counting again

[image]

To obtain a 60 seconds time you need to change the values of **R AND C** such that R= **250k ohm** , C = **100uF**

[image]

Again **this is not a perfect circuit**, you can build your own circuit based on this or use a micro-controller or a 555 timer or any other solution

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is a small microcontroller, especially considering the relatively long time of 1 minute.

Even the cheap and tiny PIC 10F200 can do this easily.  When idle, it waits for a signal to be asserted.  When that is found, the relay output is asserted, and a 1 minute timer started.  In the timing loop, it checks the input again, and resets the timer to 1 minute if it is asserted again.

Comment: I do gate controls but not much work with board level repair or build. I am familiar with relays/time-delay relays (big and dumb hardware). If I did breadboard the chip you mention I guess somehow it needs to be programmed? That is out of my skill set if so.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, a microcontroller of course needs to be programmed.  This would make a great first project if you want to learn.  Nowadays microcontrollers are circuit components like resistors and capacitors.  If you plan to design more circuits, then learning to use microcontrollers is very useful, if not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Since dry contacts are contacts which close and open with no voltage across them, I don't understand why you'd want to use dry relays for this application.

Also, I'm confused with your scenario which, to me, would make more sense if

1. Car breaks beam, gate opens and stays open as long as beam is
   broken.
2. Car drives through open gate which restores the beam, which starts a 1
   minute resettable timer.
3. If nothing breaks the beam for one minute, the timer times out and
   the gate closes.
4. If the beam is broken before the timer times out, the gate stays
   open for as long as the beam is broken.
5. Go to 2.

If that's what you want, then the circuit shown below should work for you:

The green trace shows the gate control. When it's low, the gate is open, and when it's high the gate is closed.

The red trace shows the beam-break detector output. When it's high, the beam is broken and when it goes low the timer is started.

Note that at the start the beam is broken for 2 minutes and the gate stays open all that time.  Then the car drives away, the beam is restored, and the timer starts timing out. However, 30 seconds through its timeout another car comes along and breaks the beam, which resets the timer and keeps the gate open. Two minutes later the car drives away, the beam is restored, the timer starts timing out and, with no interruptions for one minute, finally times out and closes the gate one minute after the last driver drove away.

If you care to post what voltages you have available in your system and what the signals from the beam-break detector and to the gate drive relay/(contactor?) look like I'll be happy to show you how to connect my circuit into your system.

[image]

Comment: I've seen the term "dry contact" used to mean totally floating (large common mode voltage allowed).  It's not clear whether that's what the OP means either.  I just ignored the OP's dry/wet specs since it seemed he was using terms he didn't understand.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I prefer to try to clarify an issue rather than ignore it.